# CSS - Navbar gets unblurred when text is added

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a blurry navbar and I did, but when I add text to it, the blur disappears.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone review and help?

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/TFOYnCi.jpg);
}

#topbar {
  background: #2e000eb7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#topbarbackground {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/TFOYnCi.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(30px);
  -moz-filter: blur(30px);
  -o-filter: blur(30px);
  -ms-filter: blur(30px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <!--
      Bar gets blurry when this is added
    <a id="logo">Title</a>
    -->
  <div id="topbarbackground">
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative link to [demo](https://codepen.io/NoobConfirmed/pen/NLKqoy)

Comment: Can you be more specific with the issue you are facing?

Comment: Sorry. When I add the text that is commented out in the HTML, the background of the text gets unblurred. It's supposed to be blurred. It is easier to visualize if you go and uncomment it on https://codepen.io/NoobConfirmed/pen/NLKqoy
The navbar is not supposed to get unblurred, but it gets when  I add my title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added these styles

```
#topbar {
  position: relative;
}

#topbarbackground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/TFOYnCi.jpg);
}

#topbar {
  background: #2e000eb7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#topbarbackground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/TFOYnCi.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(30px);
  -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">

  <a id="logo">Title</a>
  <div id="topbarbackground">
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzBNgZ?editors=1100)